# Upload issue involving two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables

I have an upload photos script and before confirming the upload you'd need to select an photo album (different table) that was echoed out in a drop-down.

What kind of query do I need to write for it to send (what I think would be the best) the ID of the photo as it were to be uploaded to some kind of third table where it would hold the ID of the album and photo, so I can echo out that it will only show those pictures in the selected album name.

I've been stuck with this for days and I don't know how to proceed, because I know it's an issue if you want to use multiple tables in MySQL but for me it's too late to since I made everything in MySQL instead of MySQLi.

Comment: Most of the `mysql` functions have direct `mysqli` replacements

Comment: Can you show the tables you have? At the moment I think this is a database design problem, and its essence is in your second paragraph, but I don't really follow it. If a photo can belong to just one album, then you just need two tables: `photo` and `album`. If a photo can appear in many albums, you need three tables - the third would usually be called `photo_album` to show it is a many:many.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a third table if there is not any other reason to what you said.
You can basically carry out the album id from the value of select dropdown.
 Upon submit capture this album id along with your photo.

```
<select name"album_id">
  <option value="1">album one</option>
  <option value="2">album two</option>
  <option value="3">album three</option>
</select>

//Upon submit
capture it like this:
$album_id=$_POST/REQUEST['album_id'];
```

//Place this variable value into your SQL code.